# Recreating a UUID from UUID.toString()

Tags: java, solr, cassandra

I'm currently working on a project that uses Cassandra/Solr, with a Java CRUD layer. SolrJ (at least the version that we're stuck with, doesn't play nicely with mapping Cassandra UUID or TimeUUID fields, so the recommendation that I've seen are to treat the UUID as a string in the POJO, and then let the getters and setters handle the conversion in and out.

Using `toString()` on the incoming UUID seems to work okay but, when we try to get the UUID back out from the string, we encounter problems. Using  `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(string.getBytes())` looked like it might be an answer, but that just gives us a generated UUID, based on the string, which totally breaks our primary key.

Has anyone encountered this? And, if so, did you find a solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the static `UUID.fromString(String name)` method. It accepts the String representation created in the `toString()` method and creates the UUID.

Here is the link to the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Thank you, so much - I knew it had to be out there, but was rabbit-holing way too hard!